# Is it possible to write both a queue and stack in Java using ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, queue

Is it possible to write both a queue and separate stack implementations in Java using ArrayLists?

I am tasked with writing a queue and a stack as arraylist(s) and I am not allowed to use the Java implementations of queue and stack or the defined classes as pointed out by people in my previous post, i.e I have to write my own methods.

I have seen examples where this has been done using arrays, i.e. to give array implementation of both stack and queue. I want to do the same thing but this time using an ArrayList.

Has anyone out there implemented both queue and stack using the Arraylist data type? Also are there problems I need to be aware of.I would be so grateful if you could point me to some examples.

Comment: Yep.  Next question?

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible. Give it a try. Come back with a specific question if you run into trouble.

Comment: Take a shot at it. If it doesn't work, we're here to help

Comment: yes it is possible. If you have example using arrays it should be straightforward (if you know java).

Comment: I don't know java I am learning so hence why I wanted to see some examples. I had seen some comments in books to say that arraylist implementation of queues are problematic and to stick to linked list representation

Comment: Take a look at `List.add(Object)`, `List.add(index, Object)` and `List.remove`. That should be enough hints ;)

Comment: be nice guys, don't downvote him (yet :) )

Answer (score 0):

> Also are there problems I need to be aware of

The main problem would be explaining why you are developing your own Stack and Queue when you have many built in implementations which do these.

Another problem you will have is that while Stack can be implement efficiently using ArrayList, a LinkedList is a better choice for a Queue.

> I don't know java I am learning

I would try to focus on things which are likely to be useful.  Java and its libraries are an enormous subject and you have to determine what you have to know and what you could look up if you ever needed to know.

I would suggest you have a look through this web site at least have an idea about all these products. http://java-source.net/

Comment: I assume he's implementing Stacks and Queues using an ArrayList for a homework assignment

Answer (score 0):

As spidey commented, the add and remove methods of List, as well as their dynamic nature, make implementing Stacks and Queues particularly easy. Since both ArrayList and LinkedList are Lists, either can be used as the basis for a Stack or Queue. It would be a good thought exercise to distinguish why one may or may not be better than the other for each construct.